# Adding custom rewrite rules to Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

Generally we add rewrite url in wordpress plugins as follows

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');   
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

What is procedure to add rewrite url in prestashop custom modules. 
I want to handle url request in my custom modules.
For example url request `localhost/prestashop/newpage.php` and file located at `localhost/prestashop/modules/mymodules/includes/newpage.php`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using prestashop 1.4, you can insert your custom rules in backoffice > Tools > Generators

If you are using prestashop 1.5 or later, you can modify directly the .htaccess but you should put your custom rules before the comments below

```
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums
```